# Mkdocs get current url ( Browser connected:)

Tags: python, mkdocs

So I'm trying to configure Mkdocs for my documentation, I've different folders and each one has got tasks documentation for that job
For eg - Developer (index.md, about.md), Marketing (index.md, about.md), HR(Index.md, about.md)

Now I need to create RSS feed for each Developer - Marketing - HR

My issue is how do I get the current URL users at
I checked [Plugin Config](https://www.mkdocs.org/dev-guide/plugins/#on_page_markdown)

I get the URL at build, but I need to get the URLs on page change

```
Browser connected: http://127.0.0.1:8000/developers
Browser connected: http://127.0.0.1:8000/marketing
Browser connected: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hr
```

Comment: Please, try not to include images on your posts, paste the code and output instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @MaiconMauricio apologies for that, just thought the image would be much more helpful here to understand, what I was looking for, should I remove it?

Comment: **You can replace it with the same information but in text (format it as code and it's  fine).** Also, to help others to answer your question, it's always helpful to include some relevant code. Have you started coding using this plugin? Also, maybe it's me but I couldn't understand your question. Can you try to make clearer and more detailed?

Comment: Hey @MaiconMauricio will be taking the question down, I got the solution for it. Just keeping this post up for an hour or so hoping you'd get the comment. I will keep those points in mind going forward. Thanks for your help man :)

Comment: You don't need to delete it. You can post an answer to your question, if you want to. People can have the same problem as you had...

Answer (score 0):

There is no page change event because of the design, so worked my way around by extending the `on_nav` event to get just the sections,

```
Page(title=[blank], url='/'),
Section(title='Marketing'),
Section(title='Developers'),
Section(title='HR'),
```

I'll be adding the changelog to the section titles